# F# cannot load FSharp.Core if WPF class is changed

Tags: .net, wpf, f#, fsxaml

I am using `FsXaml` with the following code

```
module Configurator

open System
open System.Windows
open FsXaml

type ConfigUI = XAML<"ConfigUI.xaml">

[<STAThread>]
let Main (pwszArgument : string) =
    let program = new Application()
    try 
        program.Run (new ConfigUI())
    with
        | :? System.IO.FileLoadException as ex -> System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ex.Message; 0
    0
```

When the line `program.Run (new ConfigUI())` is used in the F# code, the program fails to run and the debug window ouputs

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in uiXperience.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

But if I change that line to `(new Window())`, it works fine and my WPF window shows. I have made sure that `ConfigUI.xaml`, and `FSharp.Core.dll` and all of it's dependencies are in the programs working directory but I cannot figure out why it fails to load the assembly.

The main function is being called externally from a C++ program which uses `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain.`

Comment: What version of `FSharp.Core` are you building against? If it differs from `4.3`, could you add an assembly redirect?

Comment: @Caramiriel I am building it against version 4.7

Comment: @Caramiriel I don't know if I can add an assembly redirect, because I want to use `FSharp.Core.dll` `4.7`, but don't I have to have the same `FSharp.Core.dll` `4.3` in the same directory with the same filename?

Comment: The exception and disussion seem like a relic of past difficulties and I'd be surprised if they apply to current technology. Try updating everything. Make sure you are using VS2019, WPF with .Net Core, an SDK-style project, and all packages are up to date. Does the problem persist?

Comment: @CharlesRoddie Yep. Latest everything, and the problem still persists. I can't use .NET core w/WPF, because the project is in F# and the FsXaml package needs .NET framework and it's dependencies.